# String from Date not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
    -(void)viewLogAction
   {
NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:_selectedDate];
formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

NSString *convertedString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

 _allFood = [CoreDataMethods foodLogFromCoreData:convertedString];
if([_allFood count]==0)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"No data" message:@"Sorry, No food item to display on this date" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];

}
else{

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"viewLogSegue" sender:self];

}
}
```

This is my code. The NSString `_selectedDate` has value `2017-05-09`, but the line `NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:_selectedDate];` not passing any value to `date`. Please help me find out the problem.

Comment: u allocated.  **formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];** two times remove second time it will work

Comment: Did you debugged and checked the date is nil?

Comment: The code is working good. Make sure that _selected date is in correct format

Comment: `_selectedDate`  is not nil.

Comment: I given direct input to ur code its working fine.... check the value what u r passing   **_selectedDate**

Comment: check it .......  its printing as u expected ::                                            NSString * _selectedDate=@"2017-05-09";
    NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:_selectedDate];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    
    NSString *convertedString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
    
    NSLog(@"%@",_selectedDate);

    NSLog(@"%@",convertedString);

Comment: There is no issue with your code. Put breakpoint and debug. Make sure your `_selectedDate` is in format `yyyy-MM-dd` !! It hasn't underscore or dot instead of dash! Debug line by line! Print `convertedString`, `_selectedDate` and `date`!

Comment: Make sure `_selectedDate` has no whitespace (spaces, newlines) on either end of the string.

Comment: @NAVEENKUMAR your answer worked thank you. The first one. :|

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Try this

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:_selectedDate];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
```

Comment: @JohnXavier How does this fix your issue? If this works then your original code works.

Comment: @rmaddy yes I am also confused how it fixed ur issue @ JohnXavier

Comment: @JohnXavier  - what the difference found this answer

Comment: I have no idea but removing one `formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];` solved the issue. I guess this is some kind of weird case. If you want I can give you screen shots of both cases. @rmaddy @naveenkumar @anbu.karthik

Comment: @JohnXavier There is no way that removing just that one line would fix your issue. There must be more code than you are showing us. That removed line is *after* the line supposedly giving you `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is fine and will work correctly if `_selectedDate` is not nil.  Check that you are setting the value in `_selectedDate` correctly.

Comment: `_selectedDate`  is not nil. and the format is in dashes just like in the question.